# Measuring solver's memory usage with pympler

Tags: python, memory, solver, pyomo

This question is asked because I could not find a way to measure the memory usage of the cbc solver in this question [cbc solver log memory is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298605/cbc-solver-log-memory-is-missing).

Is there a way to measure the following `.solve` commands memory usage with `pympler`?

```
optim = SolverFactory('glpk')
tr = ClassTracker()
result = optim.solve(model, logfile='urbs_log.txt', tee=False)
tr.track_object(result)
tr.create_snapshot()
tr.stats.print_summary()
```

This gives me the following input:

```
---- SUMMARY ------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         active      0     B      average   pct
  SolverResults                               1     24.74 KB     24.74 KB    0%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However it is not really the right memory usage. Because when I checked the log file of the `glpk`:

```
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   1.6 secs
Memory used: 12.1 Mb (12663652 bytes)
```

**Summary:**

I am trying to measure the solvers memory usage with `pympler`. It gives me some value, but it is not the solvers memory usage. So is there a way to get `12.1 Mb` (basically memory usage of solver) with `pympler`?

*PS: It is a pyomo model*

Comment: Note that Pyomo in this case spawns a new subprocess to actually make the call to glpk. That's why you are having a hard time identify memory usage for the solver. Have you tried simply parsing the resulting glpk logfile?

Comment: Yeah from the log file I can get the memory usage. The problem is when I am not using glpk as in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298605/cbc-solver-log-memory-is-missing , instead the problem occurs when I am using cbc solver which has no memory used part in its log file. @QiChen